# How to create multidimensional array from same form fields?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tabs with same form field names, in each i want to display data like

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'     => 'Demo',
        'value'   => 'demo',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'test',
        'value'   => 'tes',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
);
```

But i get the response like below :

```
Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    [key1] => Demo
    [value1] => demo
    [compare1] => =
    [type1] => NUMERIC
    [key2] => test
    [value2] => test
    [compare2] => =
    [type2] => NUMERIC
)
```

Any solutions will be appreciated !

Comment: Please follow the instructions for a minimal, complete and verifiable example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for posting any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of array_splice and array_chunk will do the trick.

```
$new = array_merge(array_splice($arr, 0,1), array_chunk($arr, 4, true));
var_export($new);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'relation' => 'AND',
  0 => 
  array (
    'key1' => 'Demo',
    'value1' => 'demo',
    'compare1' => '=',
    'type1' => 'NUMERIC',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'key2' => 'test',
    'value2' => 'test',
    'compare2' => '=',
    'type2' => 'NUMERIC',
  ),
)
```

https://3v4l.org/eaqpk

If you need to remove the 1 and 2 in the keys then you can loop the array and use array_combine to replace the keys

```
foreach($new as &$a){
    if(is_array($a)) $a = array_combine(["key", "value", "compare", "type"],$a);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/LQil4

---

Splice the array and use preg_match to separate the word and number in the key.
Add the value to "key number -1" in the result array.

```
$new = array_splice($arr, 0,1);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    preg_match("/(.*?)(\d+)/", $k, $m);
    $new[$m[2]-1][$m[1]] = $v;
}
var_export($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/CHLGT

Comment: All the fields are not compulsory to add, than how can we use static 4 in array_chunk($arr,4,true); . So can we use dynamic chunk value ?

Comment: @RobinSingh i will help you out but am in bed right now and very tired. Will get back to you in the morning

Comment: Thanku for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set index of field name in form:

```
<input type="text" name="entity[0]key"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[0]value"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[0]compare"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[0]type"/>

<input type="text" name="entity[1]key"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[1]value"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[1]compare"/>
<input type="text" name="entity[1]type"/>
```